# Ajax-based navigation with scrapy by generating appropriate POST request

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've been trying to scrape a site that uses AJAX on link elements with onclick events to control page navigation. The scraper works for the first page, but never processes pages from there; so it seems not to be firing the POST request I build up.

I'm completely new to all of this (Python, scrapy, xPath, DOM), but my intuition is that I've mixed different structural patterns from different examples that are subtly incompatible?

I would also really appreciate some hints also on how better to debug this problem beyond (newbie) using the scrapy shell and outputting log messages.

My code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import FormRequest


class FansSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "fans"
    allowed_domains = ['za.rs-online.com/web/c/hvac-fans-thermal-management/fans/axial-fans/']
    start_urls = ['http://za.rs-online.com/web/c/hvac-fans-thermal-management/fans/axial-fans/']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Parse function called on %s', response.url)
        for component in response.xpath('//tr[@class="resultRow"]'):
            yield {
                'id': component.xpath('.//a[@class="primarySearchLink"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
            }

        next_id = response.xpath('//a[@class="rightLink nextLink approverMessageTitle"]/@id').extract_first()
        self.logger.info('Identified code of next URL as %s', next_id)

        if next_id is not None:
            first_id = response.xpath('//a[@class="rightLink nextLink approverMessageTitle"]/@onclick').\
                extract_first().split(',')[1].strip('\'')

            # POST the URL that is generated when clicking the next button
            return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                              url='http://za.rs-online.com/web/c/hvac-fans-thermal-management/fans/axial-fans/',
                                              formdata={'AJAXREQUEST': '_viewRoot',
                                                        first_id: first_id,
                                                        'ajax-dimensions': '',
                                                        'ajax-request': 'true',
                                                        'ajax-sort-by': '',
                                                        'ajax-sort-order': '',
                                                        'ajax-attrSort': 'false',
                                                        'javax.faces.viewState': 'j_id1',
                                                        next_id: next_id},
                                              callback=self.parse,
                                              dont_filter=True,
                                              dont_click=True,
                                              method='POST'
                                              )]
```

Additional information just in case it's relevant: I made these changes to the scrapy settings.py to avoid getting blocked by the webserver or getting banned:

```
# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
```

Thanks!